# How to validate multiple cells and change the values based on a condition?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use this code to convert the marks into either pass or fail values for multiple students and multiple subjects; however, for some reason, it works when I do it for one cell at a time but throws an error when I use range. I know it's a very simple code but any help will be appreciated

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Sheets("sheet1").Range("B3:E7").Value < 35 Then
        Sheets("sheet1").Range("B3:E7").Value = "Fail"
    Else: Sheets("sheet1").Range("B3:E7").Value = "Pass"

    End If

End Sub
```

> run time error 13
>   Type mismatch

Answer (score 1):

@RobertTodar's answer could be shortened to:

```
For Each Cell In Target
    Cell = IIf(Cell < 35, "Fail", "Pass")
Next Cell
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote your code would be an attempt at **recursive programming** and you are not able to do it this way in VBA. What you need in your code is a simple loop.

To loop a Range you need a variable that has the data type of Range. I'll call this variable `Cell`.

Now, in your loop, you can then use `Cell` to check and see if it is passing or failing and you have the ability to update its value as well.

```
Dim Target As Range
Set Target = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B3:E7")

Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Target
    If Cell.Value < 35 Then
        Cell.Value = "Fail"
    Else
        Cell.Value = "Pass"
    End If
Next Cell
```

Another thing you might want to look at is to get away from hardcoding your range from `Range("B3:E7")` to a more dynamic range in case something changes. You could do something like look for the last used row in column `E`. Here is an example of getting that:

```
Set Target = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B3", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

Comment: @Prince Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Doing this is helpful for people looking at this post for answers down the road. You can also mark multiple answers as useful if you find it useful to you or others. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`Sheets("sheet1").Range("B3:E7").Value < 35` in this line you are trying to compare an entire range, which is not possible quite like that.

Even if you were to pass that line, either pass or fail would populate your entire given range with their respective value.

As others suggested, a loop is necessary if you want to do this in `VBA`, though some formulas would have done a similar job, or a conditional formatting if you just wanted to see the results displayed.

See more comments in the code, hope this helps:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5") 'declare and allocate the sheet to a variable

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row at column A, assuming student names there

Dim arrData As Variant
arrData = ws.Range("B1:E" & lRow) 'declare and allocate your data to an array

Dim R As Long, C As Long
For R = LBound(arrData) + 2 To UBound(arrData) 'for each row in your data, starting at row 3
    For C = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2) 'for each column in your data
        If arrData(R, C) <> "" And IsNumeric(arrData(R, C)) Then 'only want a fail/pass for an actual number
            If arrData(R, C) < 34 Then
                arrData(R, C) = "Fail"
            ElseIf arrData(R, C) >= 35 Then
                arrData(R, C) = "Pass"
            End If
        End If
    Next C
Next R

ws.Range("B1:E" & lRow) = arrData 'allocate the data back to the sheet

End Sub
```

Assuming for this particular needs you don't have lots of data, and for each cell will do just fine, but if you have lots of data... this is a much better approach than looping through each cell.

In essence, the less you interact with the sheet, the better. In the above, you would only access the sheet twice, once to read the data, and once to write it back, with everything else being done in memory.

Comment: Thanks, this code works just fine too. I'll keep this in mind when working with bigger data. thanks again!